# Python dataframe - rolling max and min search on different colum within lines until max

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, apply, rolling-computation

I can't find a method to solve this logical challenge with Python and Dataframes, searching for a lowest value in a nr of rows, where the nr of rows is dependent on a previous calc.

Note:
I am pretty much starting level with python and dataframes - so apologies if I don't use the best code or formatting. Feel free to correct or suggest improvements so that I can learn.

```
df.columns=['Timestamp', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='ms')
df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)
maxframes = 5
df['max5'] = df['High'].shift(-maxframes).rolling(maxframes).max()
```

This results in:

| Timestamp | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume | max5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 23125.13 | 23140.47 | 23124.41 | 23133.74 | 199.09155 | **23168.90** |
| 2023-02-01 00:01:00 | 23133.74 | 23137.00 | 23123.15 | 23123.24 | 153.92866 | 23168.90 |
| 2023-02-01 00:02:00 | 23123.16 | 23145.99 | **23123.01** | 23142.98 | 204.22769 | 23168.90 |
| 2023-02-01 00:03:00 | 23144.00 | **23168.90** | 23141.75 | 23157.56 | 385.73800 | 23159.26 |
| 2023-02-01 00:04:00 | 23158.68 | 23159.26 | 23131.97 | 23133.11 | 209.27799 | 23136.90 |
| 2023-02-01 00:05:00 | 23133.11 | 23136.90 | 23086.73 | 23087.06 | 514.67716 | 23112.84 |
| 2023-02-01 00:06:00 | 23087.06 | 23112.84 | 23084.00 | 23101.51 | 425.65720 |  |
| 2023-02-01 00:07:00 | 23100.03 | 23105.14 | 23086.08 | 23086.35 | 272.72273 |  |
| 2023-02-01 00:08:00 | 23086.35 | 23104.53 | 23084.35 | 23090.76 | 218.65485 |  |
| 2023-02-01 00:09:00 | 23089.85 | 23091.31 | 23059.90 | 23067.90 | 558.62597 |  |

The challenge:
max5 results in the highest value in column High of the next 4 rows.
for each row I need to find the lowest value in colum Low in next rows (=from this row until that row where max5 is found).

example For row 1 (= 2023-02-01 00:00:00)
max5 = 23168.90, found on 2023-02-01 00:03:00
the lowest low from 2023-02-01 00:00:00 to 2023-02-01 00:03:00 is 23123.01

I guess I need to create a lambda or a separate function and use it in an apply.

A lambda seems more appropriate for shorter logic, this is a bit too complex

With a function I enountered the next issues:

1. I can't find a dataframe function that returns the rowid or rownr of the max5 value found in the High column
2. I can't find how I can calculate the lowest value in the low column in that column, in the next rows until the row where max5 is found

Comment: I see as last value in the `max5` column `23095.00`. From where is this value from?

Comment: To post this question I took an extract of the first 10 rows of a large dataset. You are right, the last 5 max5 values cause confusion, I will remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
def my_func(x):
    if x.name > len(df) - 5:
        return np.nan
    idx_max = df.loc[x.name+1:x.name+5, 'High'].idxmax()
    min_val = df.loc[x.name+1:idx_max, 'Low'].min()
    return df['High'].iat[idx_max], min_val

df = df.reset_index()
df[['max5', 'min_val']] = df.apply(my_func, axis=1, result_type='expand')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            Timestamp      Open      High       Low     Close     Volume      max5   min_val
0 2023-02-01 00:00:00  23125.13  23140.47  23124.41  23133.74  199.09155  23168.90  23123.01
1 2023-02-01 00:01:00  23133.74  23137.00  23123.15  23123.24  153.92866  23168.90  23123.01
2 2023-02-01 00:02:00  23123.16  23145.99  23123.01  23142.98  204.22769  23168.90  23141.75
3 2023-02-01 00:03:00  23144.00  23168.90  23141.75  23157.56  385.73800  23159.26  23131.97
4 2023-02-01 00:04:00  23158.68  23159.26  23131.97  23133.11  209.27799  23136.90  23086.73
5 2023-02-01 00:05:00  23133.11  23136.90  23086.73  23087.06  514.67716  23112.84  23084.00
6 2023-02-01 00:06:00  23087.06  23112.84  23084.00  23101.51  425.65720       NaN       NaN
7 2023-02-01 00:07:00  23100.03  23105.14  23086.08  23086.35  272.72273       NaN       NaN
8 2023-02-01 00:08:00  23086.35  23104.53  23084.35  23090.76  218.65485       NaN       NaN
9 2023-02-01 00:09:00  23089.85  23091.31  23059.90  23067.90  558.62597       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Not knwowing/understanding functions like series.name, idxmax() was blocking me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why is df = df.reset_index() needed ?

Comment: @Peter I'm guessing in your original DataFrame you have date index, so adding integer to this index won't work. So I reset the index to have standard integer index.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @andrej-kesely . For this example it is indeed much easier to have the numbered index rows. In my code, the timestamps are more useful as I can use time indications in the functions. You have proven to be a great help!